# PHP or PHPUnit. Select a random option from drop down excluding selected one

Tags: php

If my drop down has 10 options to select from, and option 4 is selected, how can I write the code to select an option from 1-10 exluding 4?

I know rand(1, 10) picks a random number from 1 to 10, but it sometimes can land on 4. How can I make sure that it doesn't pick the number 4, or any number that is already selected?

Comment: How is this relevant to `phpunit`?

Comment: Because I'm writing a test script in phpunit?

Comment: @RaymondYan: And I'm writing my PHP code on a Windows machine, you don't see me tagging my questions with [tag:windows] now do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like that?

```
<?php

$filtered_key = 4;

$range = range(1, 10);
unset($range[$filtered_key]);
$key = array_rand($range);

echo $key;
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you have options between 1 and n and the m-th option is selected, you can generate a number uniformly at random between 1 and n excluding m by using the following algorithm:

```
<?php
function get_rand($n,$m) 
{
  $r = rand(1,$n-1); //generate one of $n-1 numbers since $m is not selectable
  if($r >= $m) //if $r is smaller than $m we're done
    $r++;      //otherwise add one to $r
  return($r);
}
?>
```

In your case, with n=10 and m=4, we will generate a number between 1 and 9. If it is in the range [1,3] we will return that number. If it is in the range [4,9] we will add 1 and return a number in the range [5,10]. This means we return with the same probability any integer number in the range [1,3] U [5,10].

Comment: Why not just generate an array of options, and remove unfavorable options?

Comment: This works for an arbitrary range (since it runs in constant time and uses constant memory). If you have small ranges with a few filtered numbers you may prefer @SuperSkunk's answer. 
If you have large ranges with a few filtered numbers, you must use this method and a list of unwanted options to know the number to add to the random value. This is O(log(size of list of unwanted options)).